# Too many comments - Workflow improvement suggestion

Tags: discussion, review, flags, comment-flags

When a flag for "too many comments" is raised, it appears like on the snapshot below.

Showing the question / answer extract in this context is not really useful or helpful and one needs to open the post, check the comments, come back to the review page and flag / disagree.

It would make more sense to show the comments instead of the post.

---

> > > [image]

Comment: That might make sense when filtering on "too many comments" but in the general unfiltered queue I think that would by definition be too much space.